# Any finite Abelian group is Artinian module over any ring $R$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, artinian

> Finite Abelian groups are Artinian as modules over $\mathbb{Z}$

It is known that if a module $M$ has finitely many submodules it has to be Artinian. So above statement can be implied by this right!
Can I also replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with any ring $R$ (assuming $M$ is a module over $R$)?

Comment: It seems to be the case if $R$ is commutative. In the noncommutative case, you may want to consult the WIKI page on Artinian modules.